# How do I convert wav into an mxf file with timecode?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I'm looking for a way to convert wav(16bit, 48kHz, LPCM) into an mxf file with timecode.

Since ffmpeg supports mxf, I'm trying, but I don't know the command.

```
ffmpeg -i ./input.wav [hh:mm:ss.ff, name1] [hh:mm:ss.ff, name2]... ./output.mxf
```

I'm expecting the above command, but does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MXF is a pain

- The default MXF muxer requires video.
- The `-timecode` option with MXF requires video.
- The mxf_opatom muxer allows just audio, but only mono with 48000 MHz sample rate, so each channel will need to be in its own MXF file.

## Workaround 1: Pipe

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 48000 -c:a pcm_s16le -timecode 01:02:03:04 -f nut - | ffmpeg -i - -c:a pcm_s16le -f mxf_opatom output.mxf
```

- I'm assuming your audio is mono (you didn't say what it is). If your input is multichannel then [output each channel into its own file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.16mono).
- Use 01:02:03:04 for non-drop timecode, and 01:02:03.04 or 01:02:03;04 for drop.

## Workaround 2: Dummy/blank video

Just ignore the video.

#### Non-drop timecode:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=r=25 -i input.wav -timecode 01:02:03:04 -c:a copy -shortest output.mxf
```

#### Drop timecode:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=r=30000/1001 -i input.wav -timecode 01:02:03.04 -c:a copy -shortest output.mxf
```

Comment: Thank you llogan.
Can't I create an audio-only MXF? If it is possible, do you know the software to convert wav to mxf?

Comment: @goro3 See updated answer for an annoying workaround with some annoying caveats.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to output it successfully.